# Calling background method from mvc4 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, methods

I want to call method which will do something in background, but I don't want to change the current view. This is the method:

```
public ActionResult BayesTraining(string s,string path)
    {
        XmlParse xp = new XmlParse();
        using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(path)) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine("d:/xml/"+xp.stripS(s)+".xml");
        sw.Close();
    }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

As you can see, I'm currently using RedirectToAction, that just reloads the page after the method is done working. Having in mind that method doesn't effect UI, I don't want to refresh web page every time I've used it. It's job should be done in background. So, how could I call it, without the need to redirect the view?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something you can fire and forget use an ajax call. For instance if you change your action method to

```
public JsonResult BayesTraining(string s,string path)
{
    XmlParse xp = new XmlParse();
    using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(path)) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine("d:/xml/"+xp.stripS(s)+".xml");
        sw.Close();
    }

    return Json("Success");
}
```

Then in your view bind to the UI event you need to via jQuery, for instance to bind to a button with id of BayesTraining do the following

```
$("#BayesTraining").click(function(){
     $.post('@Url.Action( "BayesTraining" , "ControllerNameHere" , new { s = "stringcontent", path="//thepath//tothe//xmlfile//here//} )', function(data) {
     //swallow success here.
   });
}
```

DISCLAIMER: above code is not tested.

Hopefully it'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If the method doesn't affect the UI, does it need to return an ActionResult?  Couldn't it return void instead?

```
public void BayesTraining(string s,string path)
{
    XmlParse xp = new XmlParse();
    using (StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText(path)) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine("d:/xml/"+xp.stripS(s)+".xml");
        sw.Close();
    }


}
```